# How to create parameterization inside a loop in loadrunner ajax trueclient script?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

Parameterisation not working inside a loop in ajax true client

**HP load runner settings:**

[image: HP load runner settings]

**HP load runner settings:**

[image: HP load runner settings]

Answer (score 0):

You are not advancing the parameter inside of your loop.  Copies of this thread removed from other forums to make this one reference

http://tchelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/Content/TruClient/reference/functions.htm#TC.advanceParam(Parameter)

Comment: i just changed  update value - "on each occurence "   rather than "each iteration " in parameter settings and it worked   but 1 issue i faced transaction timing is not showing properly as it is not showing individual transaction timing